# Performance improvement for SQL count query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What type of sql query would I use to turn the following;

```
|  ID  |  SERIAL  |  LCN  | INITLCN |
|------|----------|-------|---------|
|  1   |    A     |  A1   |         |
|  2   |    B     |  A2   |         |
|  3   |    C     |  A3   |   A1    |
|  4   |    D     |  A4   |   A2    |
|  5   |    E     |  A5   |   A1    |
|------|----------|-------|---------|
```

into a result similar to this;

```
|  ID  |  COUNT  |
|------|---------|
|  1   |    2    |
|  2   |    1    |
|------|---------|
```

Using my low SQL skills, I have managed to write the below query however it is extremely slow;

```
select
  a.id,
  count (b.id) as parent
from assets a 
left join assets b
  ON (a.lcn = b.initlcn)
group by a.id
order by a.id;
```

Comment: That query shouldn't even run because of the `and` there

Comment: Firstly use an INNER JOIN, it will only return results that match, also index the join columns and lastly make sure they are TEXT or big VARCHARS, trying using ids

Comment: `and` removed. Title updated to reflect actual question.

Comment: @We0 - `INNER JOIN` reduced execution time from ~28s to ~1s. Thanks!

Comment: You can also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/457274/2319383

Comment: @Dan If you like my answer give it an up vote :D

Comment: @We0 I do not seem to have the ability to up vote comments yet. I think it requires more Rep.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
t1.ID,
t1.LCN,
COUNT(*)
from
Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.LCN = t2.INITLCN
GROUP BY t1.LCN
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e757e0/3/0).

Answer (score 0):

maybe two table join is not nesecerry .
try this

```
select 
a.id
,b.cnt
from assets a
join (
 select 
 initlcn
 count(1) cnt
 from assets
 group by initlcn
)
b on (a.lcn=b.initlcn)
```

Comment: And you joined thin air or what? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can test following query also -

I have checked the execution plan for your posted query and the following query and I am getting good difference between both -

```
SELECT t_1.Id, t_2.Cnt
  FROM Assets t_1,
       (SELECT Initlcn, COUNT(*) Cnt FROM Assets GROUP BY Initlcn) t_2
 WHERE t_1.Lcn = t_2.Initlcn
```